# How to add new command to highlight words in Listings + tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I'd like to add unrecognized/new Latex commands as keywords in listings using `tcolorbox`. I know I can use `listing options={}` and `listing style={}`, but nothing I've tried to add commands like `\SetSectionFormatting` (formatted bold like the other usual Latex macros) has succeeded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{code}{%
colframe=PaleTurquoise,
colback=PaleTurquoise!30,
breakable,
listing only, 
enhanced,
drop fuzzy shadow,
hbox,center%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{code}
\SetSectionFormatting{section}
{24pt plus5pt minus2pt} %space before
{\large\textbf{\ifHeadingNumbered
\HeadingNumber.\enspace\fi
\HeadingText}\\\rule[10pt]{\hsize}{0.4pt}}
{10pt plus3pt}%space after

\end{code}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you used `listing options={morekeywords={SetSectionFormatting}}`?

Comment: Thanks, that's it, I was writing `\SetSectionFormatting` (with a backlash). If you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass your macro as option to `listings` (option `morekeywords`). Beware that you need to use the macro name (not the macro token itself).

In your example it would be:

```
listing options={morekeywords={SetSectionFormatting}}
```